# Can I have Windows prompt me which browser to use for each link I click?

Tags: windows, browser

I would like to set up Windows so that it always asks which browser to use when it opens links.  I use different browsers for different purposes on my computer, and no single browser should be considered my "default".

I know Firefox has the "IE Tab Plus" plugin, which would probably work in most cases—but sometimes I want links to open in Chrome or in an actual IE window.

**EDIT:**
It might be OK if the page loads in a default browser, as long as I can tell that browser to always open pages from site XYZ in an external browser or with another rendering engine.

Comment: What are you using to click the links?  It is already open in a browser?

Comment: I am clicking on links from my email client, from pdf documents, from VS2008, and other applications.

Comment: If someone reads this and uses OS X, there are two solutions: [Choosy](http://www.choosyosx.com/) and [Highbrow](http://www.heliumfoot.com/highbrow).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use Chrome as my default browser, then have the IE Tab plugin decide whether the URL I click renders with Chrome or IE inside a Chrome tab.

*Example*: https:// my.intranetsite.com/internal needs to render in IE, but I want everything else to open in chrome. I installed the IE Tab plugin then went to configuration and added an Auto-url of "*my.intranetsite.com*". Now everytime I go to that page, or another page on that domain, it renders in IE by default, but my bookmarks remain consolidated in chrome. There's a similar plugin that will use Firefox to render the page inside chrome, so you can use chrome for all your URL triage needs. :D

(You could probably do the same thing using firefox as your master browser.)

**IE Tab Plugin**: https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/hehijbfgiekmjfkfjpbkbammjbdenadd

**Firefox Tab**: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/icoloanbecehinobmflpeglknkplbfbm

NOTE: This solution just changes the rendering engine, so you can view and interact with sites that are normally not compatible with chrome, but you can't access things like IE's Developer Tools when in a chrome tab, or Firefox's Firebug when in a FF tab.

Comment: Exactly the kind of solution I needed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for something similar and came across this:

https://github.com/mortenn/BrowserPicker

You can set it as your default browser and when it is launched with a URL it'll ask you which browser you want to open it in.  It also lets you add basic rules by domain name to automatically select a browser.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.

Comment: this is what i was looking for, thank you

Comment: [Browser Tamer](https://www.aloneguid.uk/projects/bt/) is a lighter alternative.

Answer (score 0):

here is a link to  FF plug-in i think its just what your looking for.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/11097/

Comment: Thanks.  I was hoping for something that would prompt me before ever loading a webpage, but now that I think about it, I suppose it would be really annoying to have to deal with a popup every time I open a page.

Now, if only this addon would let me decide that certain sites should *always* open in IE/Chrome...

Answer (score 0):

1. Install a separate Firefox installation (you can use any browser that supports separate installation)
2. Set it as the default browser.
3. Install uBlock Origin in the browser.
4. In "My filters" tab in uBlock Origin settings, set these filters to block all outcoming network requests:

   ```
   |http:$document
   |https:$document
   ```
5. In "My rules" tab in uBlock Origin settings, set this rule to block outcoming network requests from opening a local file:

   ```
   file-scheme * * block
   ```

This way, this browser can be reserved to open local files, while handling remote URLs as only displaying the URL.

### Examples

Accidentally clicking F1 in Windows File Explorer:

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3KCk.png)

As you can see, uBlock Origin handles this request and gives you an option to copy the link without parameters, so you can open it in your prefered browser without tracking parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve this can be

In the default browser picker to select "Look for an app in the Microsoft Store"
[image]

Than install any app of the offered (for this example I installed the File Downloader app).

After that choose the app that you installed as your default browser
[image]
[image]

Than uninstall the app that you choose previously

Now every time when you click some link you will get this dialog:
[image]

The only drawback to this solution is that every time you click some link you will need to uncheck the "Always use this app" checkbox or you will need to start the whole procedure again