# How can I select which browser a link from miscellaneous applications open in each time?

Tags: windows, browser

I want to be able to select which browser a link from a non-browser app opens in - similar to how Android handles link opening from non-browser apps.

Does anyone know of an application that sets itself as the default browser and then offers these choices?

Unfortunately something like [this](https://superuser.com/questions/166606/can-i-have-windows-prompt-me-which-browser-to-use-for-each-link-i-click) wouldn't be a solution for me in this case - I want it because I use all my corporate logins in Internet Explorer, and personal logins in Chrome - so I want to be able to choose which browser I open a link with (say when I click it in Outlook) so that I am already logged into the correct account in the correct browser.

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone know of an application that sets itself as the default browser and then offers these choices?

The closest app I found that fits your description is [**BrowserMaster**](http://browsermaster.codeplex.com):

[image: 1]

Comment: I couldn't get it to work on Windows 7 x64... It would just give up a random error, or if I ran it as Administrator, nothing happened. :(

Comment: Can you try the [latest beta version](http://browsermaster.codeplex.com/releases/view/34262)? According to [this review](http://www.freewaregenius.com/browsermaster-choose-your-browser-on-the-fly-whenever-you-click-on-a-link/), "Version Tested: 1.1.0 Beta (Note: I **STRONGLY** recommend installing this one over 1.0)".