# Windows 10 always ask for default browser

Tags: windows, browser

is there a way to force Windows to always ask which browser I wan't to use? I know how to set the default browser, but there is no option to unset.

Thanks for any answer.

Comment: If you want to unset which browser is the default browser, you just change the default browser, however it isn't clear which browser you want to use so I can't provide more then this comment.

Comment: @Ramhound DBR wants to be asked what program to use every time they open a link that uses a browser. Aka set the first-time-use flag. I have no idea how to set this flag though.

Comment: @Ramhound LPChip is absolute right. I don't want to set a default browser! Thats the tricky part ;)
Mainly I use FF. Sometimes I use Edge, because its fast. On the other side I use Chrome to see how the page I'm working on is turning out.

Comment: You do understand that unless changed that on Windows 10 Edge is the default browser, and likewise for any other version of Windows, IE is the default browser.  Windows use to prompt you to select your default browser due to that case in the EU, but that settlement has long expired, and didn't apply Windows 10.

Comment: @Ramhound I do understand that Edge is W10 default Browser. I just would like to have the option to decide which browser I'll take be klicking on a link in a Mail. Of course I can copy and paste the link, but thats somekind of odd. 

So just to settle this, there is just no way to achieve what I'm looking for, because there has to be a default browser at any time.

Answer (score 1):

I just found this link, I believe this is a solution for the problem. Will have a go at it.

[How do I have no default web browser, so the system asks what browser to use when I click on a link?](https://superuser.com/questions/578439/how-do-i-have-no-default-web-browser-so-the-system-asks-what-browser-to-use-whe?rq=1)