# How can I undo a default browser selection in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, browser

I utilize Chrome and IE as browsers at work and enjoyed being able to select between them.  I recently set a default browser and would like to undo this setting.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I found the following SuperUser link and verified that the registry entries exist in Windows 10 as the solution was written for an older version of Windows. This should be the fix that you are looking for. I voted to close the question since it was duplicate, but then retracted it quickly since I hadn't verified that the solution will work for Windows 10. I can no longer vote to close the question as a duplicate.
https://superuser.com/questions/578439/how-do-i-have-no-default-web-browser-so-the-system-asks-what-browser-to-use-whe

Answer (score 0):

Just go into settings, apps, default apps, scroll down till you'll see the browser you set up. Click on it and then change to the one that you want to set as default.

Comment: I think what he wants is for *neither* to be the default and to be asked to choose each time.

Comment: Alexzan you are correct.  I want neither to be selected so that it prompts me to pick which browser I'd like to use.

Comment: @JohnWinterroth well, there it is https://superuser.com/questions/578439/how-do-i-have-no-default-web-browser-so-the-system-asks-what-browser-to-use-whe

Comment: John，according to my knowledge，the default browser cannot be set to null in Windows 10.