# How to keep my No Default Browser option

Tags: windows, default-settings

I like not having a default browser. When I select a URL, a box comes up and asks me to select a browser. That's what I want.

At the bottom of the box, it asks the question, "Always use this App?" The question has a check box to indicate Yes. I uncheck it, but sometimes I forget, then I've selected a default browser. I don't want that and it's a pain to remove the default.

I'd like to have the box come up without the question checked. How can I default the question to unchecked?

[image: Dailog box "How do you want to open this"]

Comment: Thanks, but no. That's what I do now. It's frustrating to have to do that every time I forget to uncheck the option that is defaulted to checked. I'd like to change that checkmark default to unchecked, just can't find where it is located. I know it's a flag value somewhere because that same box is used for selecting App defaults and usually the option is unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

The key to making this work is removing my admin permissions. To do that, I cleared the values in the Hash parameters. I was reluctant to do that, at first, because I didn't want to mess up something in my register, so I tried it on a little-used different computer. It seems to have no effect except the desired one.

You can give it a read to [this other question](https://superuser.com/a/578440/257269).

Comment: Why did you post a new answer instead of [just editing your other answer](https://superuser.com/a/1626361/167207)?

Comment: Because editing the answer did not work.

Comment: The author already indicated the solutions in the duplicate did not answer the question.  Why wouldn't you just flag this as a duplicate instead of copying and pasting an answer from the duplicate?  Submitting a comment, then submitting another answer instead of flagging as a duplicate, is a very quick way to become an answer ban,  **Submitting 26 answers in a course of 3 hours is another.**

Comment: @Spyder “Because editing the answer did not work.” Really? You can’t edit content you posted? News to. The reality is you have downvotes on your answer. If you edited your question maybe those downvotes would go away. But now by posting the way you had you have the downvotes from that other answer, and and your posting of two answers to the same question to make your behind-the-scenes scoring worse. If you want to be a positive member of the community, you should not attempt to game the system. Instead just post good content to good questions.

Comment: "Because editing the answer did not work." - It doesn't appear like you even attempted to edit the answer, it's certainly not due to the fact, you have two user profiles (which happens more than it should).  Sadly, your submitting of two dozen answers in a very short time span, also resulted in serial downvotes.  Which does more harm than good.

Answer (score -2):

You could try registry editing, similar to the Moab suggestion, remove all http, https, url and any other web link associations from the registry.  Also ensure Windows default is not set.

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: Per the link, and unor response:

Comment: There is no link in your Answer.